# Http header - Keep Alive misunderstanding?

Tags: http, httpwebrequest

http header : `Connection: Keep-Alive`

After [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334401/http-keep-alive-and-tcp-keep-alive) alot about this , I still can't understand how its working.

[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) :

> A keepalive signal can
>   also be used to indicate to Internet infrastructure that the
>   connection should be preserved. Without a keepalive signal
>   intermediate NAT-enabled routers can drop the connection after
>   timeout.

I dont udnerstand :

a Server can have 1,000,000 cuncorrent connections .

John sends a request to the server.

Paul's compter is on the same lan near paul. paul also sends a request to the same server.

John's and paul organization is behind router.

[image]

How the hell the server knows how to keep connection alive for both paul *and* john ?

Also , when john sends request the second time , it "doesnt open a new conneciton"  , so how does keep-alive is applied here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, TCP/IP connection is not some thin wire that is temporarily connecting two computers. At the end of the day both TCP/IP and UDP are just a series of packets. It's the operating system that pretends you have a connection by putting the IP packets back together in correct order.

Now back to your question. Note that the problem is not really HTTP-specific, all of this works on TCP/IP layer. Say Paul has `192.168.0.100` and John has `192.168.0.101` internal IP addresses while NAT has public `1.2.3.4` address. When Paul connects to some server, his OS uses `192.168.0.100:54321` address (port is chosen randomly by OS). This request hits NAT which remembers that address and forwards request to external server. The external server *sees* `1.2.3.4:4321` (notice the different port) as the user is behind the NAT so internal IP is not visible.

When the external server (let it be web server) sends a reply, it sends it to `1.2.3.4:4321`. NAT, on the other hand, remembers that `4321` port should be forwarded to 192.168.0.100:54321` - and so it is.

Now imagine John sends request to the same server. This TCP/IP connection is routed through NAT which remember that request from `192.168.0.101:32123` was made. This request is then forwarded using public `1.2.3.4:4322` (notice different port). When response arrives, NAT checks the port if it is `4322`, it routes to `192.168.0.101:32123` (John). Otherwise (on port `4321`) Paul will get his reply.

Note: do not confuse [client ephemeral port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) with server port (80 in HTTP by default).

Comment: Hi. Thanks. but youre actually tell me that only 65K users can use persistant connection cause `1.2.3.4:[0..65k]`....so ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation): "*The total number of internal addresses that can be translated to one external address could theoretically be as high as 65,536 per IP address*". BTW voting to migrate, not programming related.

Comment: Tomas , People here are asking about data structures and memory allocations - (sequential or not and much more internal topics) -  which also isnt much related to _programming_...so I disagree with you about that  :-) , when I write a request  - I do want to know when and how should I use the header and raise legitimacy question.

Comment: when paul makes **second** request , does it still will be like the prev request ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: when Paul makes two concurrent requests, he uses two different ephemeral ports and NAT uses to different ports as well. When he makes two subsequent requests, most likely OS will assign different port to the second one.

Comment: According to your main answer , If it won't be persistant , what will be the difference ? will nat Wont remember where you came from ? can you spot  the difference as if there **isn't** persistant connection - so I can spot the difference. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you please answer my lst comment ?