# java socket keep alive is slow, reopening a socket is faster

Tags: java, performance, sockets, keep-alive

I am trying to come up with a java implementation of a simple HTTP client that keeps a socket open and reuses it to query other (or same) URLs on the same host.

I have a simple implementation that uses java.net.Socket but somehow the performance when I keep the socket open is worse than when I keep creating a new one.

Results first, full executable code below:

With KeepAlive: slower starting at iteration #2

```
> java -server -Xms100M -Xmx100M -cp . KeepAlive 10 true
--- Warm up ---
18
61
60
60
78
62
59
60
59
60
Total exec time: 626
--- Run ---
26
59
60
61
60
59
60
60
62
58
Total exec time: 576
```

Recreating the socket every time gives better results:

```
> java -server -Xms100M -Xmx100M -cp . KeepAlive 10 false
--- Warm up ---
188
34
39
33
33
33
33
33
34
33
Total exec time: 494
--- Run ---
33
35
33
34
44
34
33
34
32
34
Total exec time: 346
```

KeepAlive.java (standalone, no dependencies)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class KeepAlive {

    private static final String NL = "\r\n";
    private static final int READ_SIZE = 1000;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 2) {
            KeepAlive ka = new KeepAlive();
            System.out.println("--- Warm up ---");
            ka.query(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), args[1].equals("true"));
            System.out.println("--- Run ---");
            ka.query(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), args[1].equals("true"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: keepAlive <n queries> <reuse socket>");
        }
    }

    private void query(int n, boolean reuseConnection) throws Exception {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (reuseConnection) {
            open();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                long tq0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                query();
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - tq0);
            }
            close();
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                long tq0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                open();
                query();
                close();
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - tq0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total exec time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0));
    }

    private void open() throws Exception {
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.setKeepAlive(false);
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("example.org", 80));
        writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    private void query() throws Exception {
        StringBuilder req = new StringBuilder();
        req.append("GET / HTTP/1.1").append(NL);
        req.append("Host: example.org").append(NL);
        req.append("Connection: Keep-Alive").append(NL);
        req.append(NL);
        String reqStr = req.toString();

        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        writer.writeBytes(reqStr);
        writer.flush();

        String line;
        int contentLength = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("Content-Length: ")) {
                contentLength = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(16));
            }
            if (line.equals("")) {
                char[] buf = new char[contentLength];
                int offset = 0;
                while (offset < contentLength) {
                  int len = contentLength - offset;
                  if (len > READ_SIZE) {
                    len = READ_SIZE;
                  }
                  int ret = reader.read(buf, offset, len);
                  if (ret == -1) {
                    System.out.println("End of stream. Exiting");
                    System.exit(1);
                  }
                  offset += ret;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void close() throws Exception {
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Now, I'm pretty sure that either:

1. the web server sucks at handling the new requests fast ([HTTP Keep Alive and TCP keep alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334401/http-keep-alive-and-tcp-keep-alive))
2. something is wrong with the way I use the buffered reader because that's where all the time is lost but looking at the other methods available (and I tried a few), I can't find what I need to do to fix this...

Any idea how I could make this work faster? Maybe a config to change on the server itself?...

---

## Solution

As explained by *apangin* below, the slower perf is caused by Nagle's algorithm, which is enabled by default.
Using setTcpNoDelay(true), I get the updated following perfs:

Without keep-alive:

```
java -server -Xms100M -Xmx100M -cp . KeepAlive 10 false
--- Warm up ---
49
22
25
23
23
22
23
23
28
28
Total exec time: 267
--- Run ---
31
23
23
24
25
22
23
25
33
23
Total exec time: 252
```

With keep-alive:

```
java -server -Xms100M -Xmx100M -cp . KeepAlive 10 true
--- Warm up ---
13
12
12
14
11
12
13
12
11
12
Total exec time: 168
--- Run ---
14
12
11
12
11
12
13
11
21
28
Total exec time: 158
```

So here, we can see the keep-alive version performing far better than the non keep-alive one for each iteration and also if comparing total execution times. :)

Comment: you aren't really testing like for like here. In one you are hammering the server as hard as you can. On the other you are pausing quite a bit between each query. Have you tried testing total time on the client for each run?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of the test: seeing which of the two different behaviors perform the best. The question being: "how fast can I make a request and get the response with or without keep-alive". I added the total time of execution for you tho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the effect of [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).
It delays sending TCP packets in anticipation of more outgoing data.

Nagle's algorithm interacts badly with [TCP delayed acknowledgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment) in *write-write-read* scenarios.
This is exactly your case, because `writer.writeBytes(reqStr)` sends a string byte-by-byte.

Now you have two options to fix the behavior:

1. use `socket.setTcpNoDelay(true)` to disable Nagle's algorithm;
2. send the complete request in one operation: `writer.write(reqStr.getBytes());`

In both cases the reused connection will expectedly work faster.

Comment: Why wouldn't that apply to both connection types?

Comment: @EJP Obviously, `socket.close()` forces all outstanding data to be sent immediately. This does not happen for a socket kept open.

Comment: That is neither obvious nor correct, and the request still has to be sent without closing the socket. All that `close()` does as far as data is concerned is queue up a FIN to be sent after the pending data. It does not turn off the [Nagle algorithm](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc896).

Comment: @EJP If you carefully read the link you've posted, you'll realize that Nagle's algorithm delays transmission if previously sent data remains unacknowledged. This works poorly with [delayed ACK mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment). `close()` breaks this sequence: a new connection won't have unacknowledged data, and a new request will be sent almost immediately.

Comment: I've verified with `tcpdump` that client indeed delays sending the second request until the server's `ACK` arrives. This does not happen on a socket with `TCP_NODELAY` option.

Comment: Will you justify your delete vote (other than by personal antipathy)?

Comment: Thanks apangin, setting setTcpNoDelay to true (and disabling Nagle's algorithm) improved the performance of both of the tests I did. Now I get faster and equal performance for both tests (about 10ms per request-response). I still am not sure why the keep-alive wouldn't perform better than opening/closing sockets for each request though (equal performance is already some progress compared to what i had tho).

Comment: I am familiar with the Nagle algorithm, thanks. Iif you read the link I posted you will realize that the words 'close' and FIN don't occur anywhere in it, or any words to the effect of 'forces all outstanding data to be sent immediately'.

Comment: @fabien Your request-response measurements do not include `open` and `close`, which make the essential difference between two tests. Does the total execution time differ? I observe a big improvement in total time with a keep-alive connection. Please also try other hosts.

Answer (score -2):

```
reader.read(buf);
```

Your test is invalid. You aren't necessarily reading the entire response. You need to change this to a loop that counts the data returned. And if you don't read the entire response, you will be getting out of sync in the keep-alive case.

Comment: You are not wrong. The payload tested here is so small though (about ~1Kb) it doesn't matter. I added the loop to the code above and updated the results. Same, as expected.